# Update vue2 option API component to vue 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs2, vuejs3

I need to update a component from vue 2-javascript to vue 3 typescript any approach on how can I achieve this?, I watched many tutorials but it seems its more complex than I thought, here is the code:

```
<script lang="ts">
export default{
let uuid = 0;
this.$el.querySelector("input").innerHTML = "#scroll-sync-template"

data() {
    return {
      topNode: null
    }
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    this.uuid = uuid.toString();
    uuid += 1;
  },
  mounted() {
    let parent = this.$parent
    while (parent) {
      this.topNode = parent
      parent = this.topNode.$parent
    }

    const vue = this;
    this.topNode.$on('scroll-sync', function(data) {
      if (data.emitter === vue.uuid) {
        return
      }
      const {
        scrollTop,
        scrollHeight,
        clientHeight,
        barHeight
      } = data

      const scrollTopOffset = scrollHeight - clientHeight

      vue.$el.onscroll = null
      if (scrollTopOffset > barHeight) {
        vue.$el.scrollTop = scrollTop;
      }
      window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        vue.$el.onscroll = vue.handleScroll
      })
    })
    this.$el.onscroll = this.handleScroll
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll: function(e) {
      const vue = this
      window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        const {
          scrollTop,
          scrollHeight,
          clientHeight,
          offsetHeight
        } = e.target

        this.topNode.$emit('scroll-sync', {
          scrollTop,
          scrollHeight,
          clientHeight,
          barHeight: offsetHeight - clientHeight,
          emitter: vue.uuid
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <div class="scroll-sync-container">
      <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
<style>
.scroll-sync-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```

I tried to update a vue 2 in javascript document but it result in a locked road, I added the template part as the style tag.

Comment: Are you looking for Oprions API or script-setup?

Comment: I don't see `export default defineComponent(`

Comment: I priorize to update to vue 3-typescript rather than implement scrip setup with composition API

Comment: Does your component has template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do it but I thinks it's not gonna work on the '$on' :

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

  export default defineComponent({
    data: () => {
      return {
        topNode: null as any | null,
        uuid: 0,
      };
    },
    beforeCreate(): void {
      this.$el.querySelector('input').innerHTML = '#scroll-sync-template';
      this.uuid += 1;
    },
    mounted(): void {
      let parent = this.$parent;

      while (parent) {
        this.topNode = parent;
        parent = this.topNode.$parent;
      }

      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias
      const vue = this;

      if (this.topNode) {
        this.topNode.$on('scroll-sync', function (data: any) {
          if (data.emitter === vue.uuid) {
            return;
          }
          const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight, barHeight } = data;

          const scrollTopOffset = scrollHeight - clientHeight;

          vue.$el.onscroll = null;
          if (scrollTopOffset > barHeight) {
            vue.$el.scrollTop = scrollTop;
          }
          window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            vue.$el.onscroll = vue.handleScroll;
          });
        });
        this.$el.onscroll = this.handleScroll;
      }
    },
    methods: {
      handleScroll: function (e: any) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias
        const vue = this;

        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight, offsetHeight } = e.target;

          if (this.topNode) {
            this.topNode.$emit('scroll-sync', {
              scrollTop,
              scrollHeight,
              clientHeight,
              barHeight: offsetHeight - clientHeight,
              emitter: vue.uuid,
            });
          }
        });
      },
    },
  });
</script>
```

You can still type your topNode if you want with 'ComponentPublicInstance' from 'vue' but you will have an error on the $on. Maybe the solution is to use addEventListener or a substitute.

If you want to migrate to Composition API don't hesitate to ask, and i think it could solve some problems :)

Hope it helps you !

Comment: I would be useful to try it in composition API

Comment: I reach this point but is not working yet https://github.com/enlazoCtrl/scrollbarTesting